# How to install Android from Google on a Chinese Android phone?

Tags: custom-roms, vanilla-android

I have Android v85a bought from China. It has FuntouchOS installed. I want to change that to some latest compatible version of Android from Google.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is the device Android Treble compatible (there are apps in PlayStore  that can test this)?

Comment: What Android Treble ?

Comment: [Android Treble](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=android+treble) is an important technology required for using the AOSP Generic System Image provided by Google. As Android is not an device generic OS like Windows or Linux on a non-Treble device you need an Android version compiled exactly for your device.